# Python pandas dataframe sort_values does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame which I want to sort by 'test_type'

```
  test_type         tps          mtt        mem        cpu       90th
0  sso_1000  205.263559  4139.031090  24.175933  34.817701  4897.4766
1  sso_1500  201.127133  5740.741266  24.599400  34.634209  6864.9820
2  sso_2000  203.204082  6610.437558  24.466267  34.831947  8005.9054
3   sso_500  189.566836  2431.867002  23.559557  35.787484  2869.7670
```

My code to load the dataframe and sort it is, the first print line prints the data frame above.

```
        df = pd.read_csv(file) #reads from a csv file
        print df
        df = df.sort_values(by=['test_type'], ascending=True)
        print '\nAfter sort...'
        print df
```

After doing the sort and printing the dataframe content, the data frame still looks like below.

Program output:

```
After sort...
  test_type         tps          mtt        mem        cpu       90th
0  sso_1000  205.263559  4139.031090  24.175933  34.817701  4897.4766
1  sso_1500  201.127133  5740.741266  24.599400  34.634209  6864.9820
2  sso_2000  203.204082  6610.437558  24.466267  34.831947  8005.9054
3   sso_500  189.566836  2431.867002  23.559557  35.787484  2869.7670
```

I expect row 3 (test type: sso_500 row) to be on top after sorting. Can someone help me figure why it's not working as it should?

Comment: Looks like it's sorting by `test_type`, which is a string, which sorts lexicographically. I think you probably need to split on `_` and zfill to 4 the "numerical" part of that column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumbaly, what you're trying to do is sort by the numerical value after `sso_`. You can do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df.ix[np.argsort(df.test_type.str.split('_').str[-1].astype(int).values)
```

This

1. splits the strings at `_`
2. converts what's after this character to the numerical value
3. Finds the indices sorted according to the numerical values
4. Reorders the DataFrame according to these indices

**Example**

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'test_type': ['sso_1000', 'sso_500']})

In [16]: df.sort_values(by=['test_type'], ascending=True)
Out[16]: 
  test_type
0  sso_1000
1   sso_500

In [17]: df.ix[np.argsort(df.test_type.str.split('_').str[-1].astype(int).values)]
Out[17]: 
  test_type
1   sso_500
0  sso_1000
```

Comment: I just tested this and you are right. What I ultimately did is rearrange the string in my other program (csv generator) that makes it 500_sso instead of sso_500. It seems to have solved my problem, I just have to keep it in mind to generate my test type strings this way.

Comment: `500_sso` should still be sorting after `1500_sso`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could also extract the numbers from `test_type` and sort them. Followed by reindexing `DF` according to those indices.

```
df.reindex(df['test_type'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)    \
                          .astype(int).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]