# What is the issue with my date sorting in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to sort the dates in pandas using the standard method, the dates are converted to timestamps

```
 # open the merged data csv as df veriable
df = pd.read_csv(raw_data)

# turns the dates from an object into a pandas recognizes date format
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')

#should sort the dates from latest to oldest but doesnt sort at all
df.sort_values(['Start Date'], ascending= True, kind= 'quicksort')
```

My data frame has lots of entries for the same dates and has over 1000 entries this may play a part in not sure. The data frame makes no change at all.

Comment: where did you assign changes back to the dataframe?....assign those changes back to initial dataframe by `df=df.sort_values(['Start Date'], ascending= True, kind= 'quicksort')`

Comment: If you want to change the original dataframe you need to add `inplace=True`: `df.sort_values(['Start Date'], ascending= True, kind= 'quicksort', inplace=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Pandas DataFrame not display new order using \`sort\_values\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613581/why-does-my-pandas-dataframe-not-display-new-order-using-sort-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.
Edit last line, either

```
df = df.sort_values(['Start Date'], ascending= True, kind= 'quicksort')
```

or

```
df.sort_values(['Start Date'], ascending= True, kind= 'quicksort', inplace=True)
```